# Capistrano 3 Deploy to Vagrant Box

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant to run a mock of my production server, and trying to deploy to it via Capistrano 3. Because vagrant is forcing me to use port 2222, I added it to the server in my test.rb stage file. When I run `cap test deploy`, it prompts for the password and runs nearly everything, but when it gets to moving the precompiled assets to the Vagrant box it seems that it isn't using the port on the server. It prompts for my password again and after entering the correct one three times, it craps out every time. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/DevanB/8403955) of the log, my test.rb and deploy.rb. I'd like to precompile my assets locally then push them, but can't figure out my port issue, to verify all of everything is good before I go to production.

Thanks for any help!